# 2011 EVENT - Sorting out tags, wiki excerpts

Tags: discussion, tagging, events

Yes it's a boring topic for most, but for those amongst us who really want to get this sorted out, it's time to have an event.

Last month (Oct 31) we had an answering event, and did a massive cleanout of the unanswered questions, which was fantastic.  With a surge of traffic this month and a lot of new users asking questions on new topics, our tags have grown, and we've had much debate on plurals vs singulars and the like.

As such, an event (unfortunately it'll require that you have enough points to suggest tag edits and the like) to add these and approve them should help with this - if all the descriptions for tags are there, people are more likely to use the right ones.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule for registration, come one come all, 9.30am UTC on November 30th, 2011.

Comment: How is this question "unclear what you're asking?" It was about inviting people to a tag cleanup event five years ago. It's perfectly clear.

Comment: @pnuts it's a meta post. It need not be an actual question. We keep linking you to http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/a-friendly-reminder-that-this-is-meta-questions-here-do-not-have-to-be-question. The software calls everything on meta a question, but it's perfectly fine to just have non-question posts about how the site works.

Comment: @pnuts That page lists many examples of things that are not questions (posting bugs, suggesting features, discussing policies). You have been determined to enforce a policy of questions only on meta that goes against the longstanding precedent of this site, the practices of other SE meta sites, and community concensus. Why?

Comment: @pnuts This post is fine. Most posts on meta are fine. They don't all need answers and they don't all have to be questions. The concensus view, with an astonishing 33 upvotes and one downvote, is that we don't want to close stuff like this on meta (as opposed to the main site, where the criteria is obviously different). If you believe meta should work differently, then you should make a proposal and state your reasoning, not simply continue to ignore community concensus when many users have repeatedly told you what that concensus is.

Comment: I do not see any need to close properly located question on Meta. Only question that should not be here should be closed.